# 5 section bow window with one pane cloudy

Tags: repair, windows

My front 5-section bow window has one section where the seal is broken between the panes.  It is now cloudy.  Can the one pane be removed and a new window put in?

The window should be covered by a warranty, except the company is out of business.   I would hire a glass specialist if the one section can be replaced.

Comment: Even if you could get that pane out, chances are slim that you'll find an exact replacement to drop in the opening.  I've seen some aftermarket repair services who drill a tiny hole in the glass, remove the trapped moisture, insert some desiccant to help prevent a recurrence, and refill the space with inert and dry gas.  I'm sure there is a local outfit that does that in your area.

Comment: Are we talking about a movable or stationary section? Is this a 100% vinyl window or a wood-core unit?

Comment: @jwh20 That sounds like an answer to me, especially if you can give Googlable terms for finding such a service. (Yes, this is probably a "shopping" question, but seems generally useful to me...)

Comment: Are many of these windows glazed with tempered glass at least at the bottom for a window that goes almost to the floor? AFIK one cannot drill into tempered glass. I would think the drilling would be done through the  frame. Where is this cloudy pane located in the window? Is the pane fixed or part of a movable window?

Answer (score 1):

We've had this problem (and my father-in-law had it too), but in our case, just because the windows were old.

Yes, a glazier will be able to replace the panels.  To answer jwh20's comment about "you won't find an exact replacement to drop in the opening", the panels are made to measure (and you want the *glazier* to do the measuring).

Answer (score 0):

I helped a friend with a cloudy (moisture) double glazing unit.

We drilled two small holes into the unit and with a small suction pump sucked air out one hole - the other hole had air that came through a plastic box full of dessicant and it took two days but worked.

We then blocked the holes with two small rubber bungs.. Two years later and we have not had to do it again - but we have the bits ready...